# jQuery datatable: How to reset row reordering sequence after deleting a row

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery datatable with row reorder feature allowing a user to changing the sequence of rows drag and drop. There is an issue that when I delete a row from jQuery datatable on client side, the row order sequence does not reset. Is there any in-built function in jQuery datatable which allows to reset index after a row is deleted?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you, by chance, figure this out?  Dealing with it now...

Answer (score 0):

```
var myTable= $('#myTable').DataTable({
        "columnDefs": [{
            "searchable": false,
            "orderable": false,
            "targets": 0
        }],
        "order": [[1, 'asc']]
    });
myTable.on('order.dt search.dt', function () {
        myTable.column(0, { search: 'applied', order: 'applied' }).nodes().each(function (cell, i) {
            cell.innerHTML = i + 1;
        });
    }).draw();

function deleteRow() {
    tabelSigner.on('click', 'tbody tr', function () {
        tabelSigner.row(this.rowIndex - 1).remove().draw();
    });
}
function addRow(id, name) {
    tabelSigner.row.add([
        tabelSigner.data().length + 1,
        "<a class='btn btn-warning btn-xs' href='#' onclick = 'deleteRow()'><i class='fa fa-check-circle'>&nbsp;Pilih</i></a>",
        name
    ]);
    tabelSigner.draw();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try calling "draw()" function after removing the row on client side; which would ideally refresh the grid with the latest data (i.e., after deletion). Refer the link below.

[Draw function description from DataTables website](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw())

Hope this Helps!!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I have tried it and doesn't work for me.